# Not getting connection string value in wcf service method

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, connection-string

I am having 1 class library named as **AuxiliaryLib** which contains app settings like below:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="connectionstring" value="Data Source=My-Pc;Initial Catalog=Db1;User ID=StackOverflow;Password=123456"></add>
  </appSettings>
```

Now, in this class library I have 1 class file which return connection string like below:

```
public static string ReturnConnectionString()
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionstring"];
        }
```

I have 1 wcf project in which i have given reference of above class library i.e **AuxiliaryLib** and calling above connection string method but I am getting null.

```
 Public void MyMethod()
       {
         var connectionRepo = new ConnectionRepo();
         string str  = ConnectionRepo.ReturnConnectionString(); //getting null
       }
```

I have web.config in wcf project where I have added connection string but still getting null:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    <add key="connectionstring" value="Data Source=My-Pc;Initial Catalog=Db1;User ID=StackOverflow;Password=123456"></add>
  </appSettings>
 <!--<connectionStrings>
    <add name="connectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=My-Pc;Initial Catalog=Db1;User ID=StackOverflow;Password=123456"></add>
  </connectionStrings>-->



 Public void MyMethod(string regionId)
           {
               string str = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString; // null
               string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionstring"];// null
           }
```

**Note :** MyMethod is running on threadpool:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(MyMethod), new object[] { regionId });
```

Comment: If it's not an Asp.Net project, then use App.config instead of Web.config and it should work.

Comment: `MyMethod` would not even compile so we are not looking at your actual code - which means you could be leaving something out that is necessary to find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try....

```
using System.Web.Configuration;

WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionstring"]
```